# Change Media BreakPoint for _LoginPartial in Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4

I am have scaffolded a NavBar in a .Net Core application using Bootstrap 4.  It looks like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-toggleable-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Home/Home">MyApp</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light"  asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
                     <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 6</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_Menu" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Because there are numerous items in the Menu, I have changed navbar-toggleable-sm to navbar-toggleable-lg so that the hamburger menu appears at a wider media breakpoint and "Login" does not sit on top of the menu at widths smaller than lg.  While this works fine for displaying the hamburger menu, the "Login" menu item continues to show as the media width is being narrowed until the small size is reached.

How can I ensure that the _Login disappears under the hamburger menu at media widths of smaller that lg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no class name called `navbar-toggleable-lg` in **bootstrap 4.3.1**. It has been replaced with `navbar-expand-lg`. So remove `navbar-toggleable-lg`.

Now if you use `navbar-expand-lg` then you also have to use `d-lg-inline-flex flex-lg-row-reverse` instead of `d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse`.

So your full navbar code should be as follows:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Home/Home">MyApp</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-lg-inline-flex flex-lg-row-reverse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light"  asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
                     <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Item 6</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_Menu" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```